# CSS class is not working properly

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code in my HTML file

```
echo "<article class='room-full-width'>";
$room_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM roomdetails WHERE hotelname = '".$row['hotelname']."'");       
while($room=mysql_fetch_array($room_query)){
    echo "<span class='room-details'>";
    echo "<span class='room-name'>";
    echo $room['roomtype'];
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<a class='gradient-button' title='Book now' href='hotel.html'>Book now</a>";
    echo "</span>";
}
echo "</article>";
```

And I am adding this following Style in .css file:

```
.room-full-width{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.room-full-width .room-details{
    background-color: -moz-buttonhoverface;
    float: left;
    padding: 1% 2% 0;
    width: 90%;
}

.room-full-width .room-details .room-name{
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    max-width: 30%;
    overflow: visible;
    width:29%;
}

.room-full-width .room-details .gradient-button{
    bottom: 5px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
}
```

But this class *.room-full-width* is not at all working , if I test it with my firebug it is not even showing this class but other classes like `.room-details` and `.room-name` and `.gradient-button` all are working fine.

But the parent class is not at all shown in Firebug itself.

I am using latest version of Firefox - it supports HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: Can you explain more on the "it is not even showing this class..."

Comment: What browser are you using? (just wondering if it supports `article` or not)

Comment: I am Using Mozilla Firefox 28.0 Version (latest version)

Comment: The parent Class(.room-full-width) is not displayed in Firebug but all of its Child classes are shown

Comment: did you even include the file with css styles?

Comment: try adding `<article class='room-full-width'>` without php tag.

Comment: PHP TAG - what diffrence it will create with or without PHP tag , i think all will work in same procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

`echo "<article class=\"room-full-width\">";`

It might be the single quotes it's not agreeing with.

Or better yet:

`echo '<article class="room-full-width">';`